How to automatically configure Docker config in Gitlab CI/CD variables?
I have some Docker components and I want to store the credentials (Docker config) in a project variable in the CI/CD settings.
In the CI/CD variables settings I can set the raw config text as a variable such as $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG, eg:
Type: Variable
Key: DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Value: {"auths":{"registry.redhat.io":{"auth":"<base64>"}}}

Then in a job I'll have to send the config to the appropriate file to use it:
my_job:
  before_script:
    - echo "$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG" > ~/.docker/config.json

I'm trying to eliminate this step if possible. I've tried changing the CI/CD variable type to a File instead and using Docker's $DOCKER_CONFIG variable that it references for the config path:
Type: File
Key: DOCKER_CONFIG
Value: {"auths":{"registry.redhat.io":{"auth":"<base64>"}}}

This now creates the file <project path>/<project>.tmp/DOCKER_CONFIG with the contents of the DOCKER_CONFIG file being the variable value and the $DOCKER_CONFIG variable is the path to that file.
This seems like the right solution, but it turns out that Docker assumes $DOCKER_CONFIG is a directory and it looks for a config.json file within that directory (e.g.: <project path>/<project>.tmp/DOCKER_CONFIG/config.json).
Between the Gitlab project variables and Docker's environment variables, is there any way to configure those so that any Docker commands will automatically have the appropriate Docker configuration without the extra step of echo "$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG" > ~/.docker/config.json in every Docker job?

so just create a Key: MYFILE secret and cp $MYFILE ~/.docker/config.json?
